# Spring oauth2 hasRole access denied

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-oauth2

I am really new to OAuth2 and trying to build one server in roles auth.server for authorizing users and one keeping a protected resource...

I've got issues to secure with the ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter. It seems like he is ignoring all it's roles fetching form userInfoUrl...

so here the code:

**AuthServer**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableResourceServer
@RestController
public class Oa2AuthServerApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Oa2AuthServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

__

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("ADMIN", "USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("user")
                .password("user")
                .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

__

```
@Configuration
public class OA2AuthConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("default")
                .secret("kx")
                .scopes("AUTH", "TRUST")
                .autoApprove(true)
                .authorities("ROLE_GUEST", "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "implicit", "refresh_token");
    }
}
```

**ResourceServer**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
public class Oa2ResourceServerApplication {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String greet() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "\r\n";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/forAdmin")
    public String admin() {
        return "hi admin!";
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Oa2ResourceServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

So getting token from authserver + calling "localhost:9091/" and "/forAdmin" works with this token.

But when I do this:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/forAdmin").hasRole("USER");
    }
```

I get access denied....

to be sure, the roles are reaching the resource server, i have changed the geet() from above to

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String greet(Principal user) {
        if (user instanceof OAuth2Authentication) {
            log.info("having roles: {}", ((OAuth2Authentication) user).getAuthorities());
        }
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "\r\n";
    }
```

and the console shows

d.k.auth.Oa2ResourceServerApplication    : having roles: [{authority=ROLE_USER}]

So when "Principal" is the currently authenticated user, I assume there is a bug with the resourceserverer configurer....or I am doing something fatally wrong...

or both....I don't know

does anybody can help me in this problem?

Answer (score 4):

So JWT is necessary, without it does not work.

I solved it with the combination:

```
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('openid') and hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

You can find a sample of a protected Resource [here](https://github.com/mavogel/uaa-behind-zuul-sample/blob/master/dummy-service/src/main/java/com/kakawait/DummyServiceApplication.java).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing roles prefixing.

From Spring Security 4.x roles has to be prefixed, for e.g. if you are doing

```
.antMatchers("/forAdmin").hasRole("USER");
```

you have to change it to:

```
.antMatchers("/forAdmin").hasRole("ROLE_USER");
```

> Roles are processed by the RoleVoter and having a prefix lets the
>   voter know which tokens are role names so it can ignore ones it can't
>   process. For example you can specify
>   "ROLE_ADMIN,IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" but you wouldn't want that voter
>   to process IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY - AuthenticatedVoter should handle
>   that.

From the official [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.html):

> Votes if any ConfigAttribute.getAttribute() starts with a prefix
>   indicating that it is a role. The default prefix string is ROLE_, but
>   this may be overridden to any value. It may also be set to empty,
>   which means that essentially any attribute will be voted on. As
>   described further below, the effect of an empty prefix may not be
>   quite desirable.

Comment: thanks, but I tried all things like "hasRole", "hasAutorhity" "#oauth2.clientHasRole"......it goes more strange....i even could query "#oauth2.hasScope('AUTH')....which the client has...and this also results in a access denied

Answer (score 2):

I had a simililar problem when connecting a client to my AuthServer. I found out that when the client is parsing the roles given from the server it uses a AuthoritiesExtractor. Default one used is FixedAuthoritiesExtractor.

The code in the FixedAuthoritiesExtractor has a method to convert a Map with authorities to a List of GrantedAuthority and as part of this it fetches the name of the roles in a method called asAuthorities.

```
private String asAuthorities(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof Collection) {
        return StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString((Collection<?>) object);
    }
    if (ObjectUtils.isArray(object)) {
        return StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString((Object[]) object);
    }
    return object.toString();
}
```

When debugging this i can see that the Object comming in is a List but the content of that list is a Map. So its a `List<Map<String,String>>`. Inside the map it contains a entry with key authority and value role.

Lets say we have the role `ROLE_USER` on the AuthServer.
When using toString on a map object it converts this to the String `{authority=ROLE_USER}`.
If you check if the user now contains a role name `ROLE_USER` it will not be equal to the name `{authority=ROLE_USER}`

I therefore created a new version of the AuthoritiesExtractor.

```
public class OAuth2AuthoritiesExtractor implements AuthoritiesExtractor {

    static final String AUTHORITIES = "authorities";

    @Override
    public List<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Map<String, Object> map) {
        String authorities = "ROLE_USER";
        if (map.containsKey(AUTHORITIES)) {
            authorities = asAuthorities(map.get(AUTHORITIES));
        }
        return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(authorities);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private String asAuthorities(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof Collection) {
            return (String) ((Collection) object).stream().map(o -> {
                if (o instanceof Map) {
                    return ((Map) o).values().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
                }
                return o.toString();
            }).collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        }
        if (ObjectUtils.isArray(object)) {
            return StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString((Object[]) object);
        }
        return object.toString();
    }

}
```

When using this extractor it detects that the collection contains a Map - and if it does it uses the values in that map as role names.

The role i get now in spring security is stripped of the `{authority=` part and now only contains the String `ROLE_USER`, and the checks to see if `isUserInRole` now works.

Comment: Where did you add this extractor?

Comment: @mad_fox When configuring HttpSecurity (configure(HttpSecurity)) you can use the addFilterBefore method to add a filter that contains UserInfoTokenServices with the authoritiesextractor set. Let me know if you need a more concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that token exchange via userInfoUri is not working properly. You are able to secure resources servers from beeing accessed unauthorized, but the access() method in HttpSecurity configuration always seem to deny a request.

Adding a JWT token store fixed this.

I wrapped a more detailed explanation of this into a blog article here: [stytex.de/blog/2016/02/01/spring-cloud-security-with-oauth2/](http://stytex.de/blog/2016/02/01/spring-cloud-security-with-oauth2/)

Answer (score 0):

My endpoints looks like this:

```
    @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Authorization token",
                    required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header") })
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @PutMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void updateStory(@RequestBody StoryDTO story) {

        LOGGER.info("Updating story with title: {}", story.getTitle());
        storyService.updateStory(story);
    }
```

I have tried

```
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

but only works for me

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

You are probably missing this configuration:

```
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity // THIS !!!
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) // THIS !!!
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode(ADMIN_PASSWORD)).roles("ADMIN").and()
                .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode(USER_PASSWORD)).roles("USER");
    }
}
```

I use Spring boot 2 - 2.1.9.RELEASE

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
If you want to use @PreAuthorize("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") you need to register [OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/expression/OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add `AuthoritiesExtractor` implementation and then add it as a bean in the `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`:

```
 public class OAuth2AuthoritiesExtractor implements AuthoritiesExtractor {

    static final String AUTHORITIES = "roles";

    @Override
    public List<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Map<String, Object> map) {
        ArrayList<String> authorities = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (map.containsKey(AUTHORITIES)) {
            Arrays.stream(((String) map.get(AUTHORITIES)).split(",")).forEach(s -> {
                authorities.add("ROLE_".concat(s.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)));
            });
        }
        return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(String.join(",", authorities));
    }
}
```

Then add a bean in `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` implementation:

```
 @Configuration
    public class ResourcesConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter implements Filter {
    
        @Bean
        public AuthoritiesExtractor githubAuthoritiesExtractor() {
            return new OAuth2AuthoritiesExtractor();
        }
}
```